# Laravel Function - What is the good way to do the event fucntion

Tags: php, laravel

now I have a add_rank_point() method and this method is process to add rank point to the user point transaction table. So I want to trigger another function check_up_level() method when I add rank point to the user, this check_up_level() method is process to upgrade the user level if the rank point is hit.

so what is the good way I should use in this case, I follow the Coding SOP so one function I just process 1 method, like add_rank_point() just process to add rank point.

Should I use the laravel Events as well?

I am a beginner at Laravel, so trying to wrap my head around the proper Laravel way of doing things. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You can use eloquent observers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.